# createRequestFactory with google-api-java-client-1.15.0-rc

Tags: android, json, parsing, header, google-places-api

I have to implement this method, but most of libs are deprecated.
I need a new version compatible with client 1.15.0rc.

```
public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(
        final HttpTransport transport) {
    return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
            GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
            headers.setApplicationName("AndroidHive-Places-Test");
            request.setHeaders(headers);
            JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
            request.addParser(parser);
        }
    });
}
```

The things I can't solve are:

```
GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
```

and

```
JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm also running the same problem here. So far I have solved the json dependencies adding the following library:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
   <version>1.15.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
```

and replacing:

```
JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
request.addParser(parser);
```

with:

```
JsonObjectParser parser = new JsonObjectParser(new JacksonFactory());
request.setParser(parser);
```

I'll let you know how to solve the GoogleHeaders dependency as soon as I solve it myself.

EDIT: It looks like they removed this class in release 1.14 (see [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=660)) in favor of HttpHeader. Change GoogleHeaders with HttpHeader and replace setApplicationName with setUserAgent, like below:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setUserAgent("AndroidHive-Places-Test");
```

Comment: Import errors are gone :) but I got a doubt because JacksonFactory.class is at google-http-client-jackson2-1.18.0-rc and google-http-client-jackson1-1.18.0-rc. What's the difference between these jars?